# How to update existing model when another is created?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have two models, User, and Product. Product belongs to User, User has many Products.

When a Product is created I also want to update multiple fields in the User model. I've been developing with Ruby for like 2 years now and still don't understand forms fully when it comes to this stuff. I'm still getting `permitted: false`. Now I know that for instance if I was creating a `user` while also creating a `product` I would just do `@product.user.build` but in this case I just want to update an already existing record.

I also realize that I probably can't call `f.fields_for :user` as `@product` doesn't know about user yet. In my head I believe I should be able to just pass additional `params` to the form, grab the `current_user` in the `product#create` action and then update the attributes manually by calling `update_attributes` on user.

*product.rb*

```
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :user
```

*product controller*

```
def new
  @product = Product.new
end

params.require(:product).permit(:product_name, user_attributes: [:phone_number, :email_address])
```

*product view*

```
form_for @product do |f|

  f.fields_for :user do |c|

    c.text_field :phone_number
    c.text_field :email_address

  f.text_field :product_name
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I also realize that I probably can't call f.fields_for :user as @product doesn't know about user yet.

You can assign attributes to @product without saving it.

```
def new
  @product = Product.new(
    user: current_user
  )
end
```

Now `@product.user` works.

Comment: And still use this syntax `f.fields_for :user` ?

Comment: @Kenyounot Yes, it works as in [Building Complex Forms](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#building-complex-forms). There will be an extra parameter for the user ID, be sure to permit that.